# Angular 2 - On refreshing routed page...Not able to find component if refreshed only on route I am going using navigate

Tags: angular

Real newbie with angular 2 and new version of es2015
I a

App Structure

```
       app
       |---js
           |-- All js files
       |---ts
           |--- html 
         |--- contact_display.html
         |--- contact_block.html
         |--- edit_contact_form.html
         |--- navbar.html
         |--- new_contact_form.html
           |--- main.ts
           |--- contact_display.component.ts
           |--- contact_block.component.ts
           |--- edit_contact.component.ts
           |--- navbar.component.ts
           |--- new_contact.component.ts
           |--- contact.service.component.ts
           |--- contact.ts
           |--- contact.service.component.ts
           |--- mock_contact.component.ts
           |--- typings
         |-- underscore 
            |--- underscore.d.ts
       |---node_modules
       |---resources
       |---typings
       |--- index.html
       |--- package.json
       |--- tsconfig.json
       |--- typings.json
```

Files are as such
**Main.ts**

```
          import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
          import { Component, provide } from 'angular2/core';
          import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
          import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';
          import { ContactDisplayComponent } from './contact_display.component';
          import { NewContact } from './new_contact.component';
          import { EditContact } from './edit_contact.component';



          @Component({
            selector:'app-start',
            template:`
            <navbar></navbar>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            `,
            directives : [NavbarComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
          })

          @RouteConfig([
            {path:'/',name:'Home',component:ContactDisplayComponent},
            {path:'/New_Contact',name:'New_Contact',component:NewContact},
            {path:'/Edit_Contact/:id',name:'Edit_Contact',component:EditContact}
          ])

          export class Main{
          }


          bootstrap(Main,
            [
              ROUTER_PROVIDERS
            ]
          );
```

I use navigate to route to go to the Edit Contact Page

```
        import { Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
        import { ContactBlockComponent } from './contact_block.component';
        import { ContactService } from './contact.service';
        import { Contact } from './contact';
        import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router } from 'angular2/router';


        @Component({
        selector  :'contact-display',
        templateUrl:'app/ts/html/contact_display.html',
        styleUrls : ['../resources/contact_detail.css'],
        directives:[ ContactBlockComponent, ContactBlockComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
        providers:[ContactService]
        })

        export class ContactDisplayComponent
        {
        public contacts:Contact[];
        isSelected:boolean;
        selectedContact;

        constructor(private _contactService:ContactService, private _router:Router){
            this.isSelected = true;
        }

        onContactSelection(contact_picked){
            console.log(contact_picked.contact_phone);
            this.selectedContact = contact_picked;
            return false;
        }

        getContacts(){
            this._contactService.getContacts().then((contacts:Contact[]) => this.contacts = contacts);
        }

        /********* Navigate to Edit Contact ****************

        onEditContact(contact_picked){
            let userId = contact_picked.id;
            this._router.navigate(['Edit_Contact',{id:userId}]);
        }

    }
```

Errors on console are like this

> GEThttp://localhost:3000/app/js/navbar.component 404 (Not Found) 
>   GEThttp://localhost:3000/app/js/contact_display.component 404 (Not Found)
>   Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) link http://localhost:3000/app/js/navbar.component(…) 
>   GEThttp://localhost:3000/app/js/new_contact.component 404 (Not Found)
>   GEThttp://localhost:3000/app/js/edit_contact.component 404 (Not Found)

All these file are those which I import in main.ts and in the same order

```
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';
import { ContactDisplayComponent } from './contact_display.component'; 
import { NewContact } from './new_contact.component'; 
import { EditContact } from './edit_contact.component';
```

Index file containing system config which is

```
        <script>
            System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            },
            paths: {
                underscore: '/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js'
            }
            });
            System.import('/app/js/main.js')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        </script>
```

Comment: What happens when you change in the `system.config`, the property `app` in packages to `app/js`?

Comment: I did that PierreDuc ,,,   app/js: {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
                }it generates an error Uncaught Syntax error : Unexpected Token / .  For the idea that js files are in app/js folder in tsconfig.json file -- outDir:"/app/js"  to know where is output directory

Comment: So everything works, up until the point you press refresh on a routed page?

Comment: Yes PD page is static right now so it is showing message in template so yes working before reloading  --  this is link to complete code [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6bmoy5m7lp06tr/phonebook_01.zip?dl=0     just do npm install and npm start and we are good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your project, and the reason it doesn't work on refresh, is because the webserver doesn't redirect the request to the `index.html`. To bypass this, you can use the [`HashLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/HashLocationStrategy-class.html), as explained in the docs, or have your develop and production webserver redirect the initial request to `index.html`:

```
bootstrap(Main, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

Besides that, I suggest you use this `System Config`, hence the quotes around `'app/js'` and the removal of `.js` in the `System.import`:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    'app/js': {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },
  paths: {
      underscore: '/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js'
  }
});
System.import('/app/js/main')
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Or, before you proceed any further with this project, update to the `rc.1` version of Angular2, where everything has changed..

Comment: Appreciate your help , implemented HashLocationStrategy and also found out wrong placement of <base href="/"> in index.html file .. By the way can you tell me how to update to rc.1 version of angular 2 ?

Comment: A good start would be to look at their updated [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). The different modules of `angular2` are split up, and are now loaded through `SystemJS`. The main thing you have to do is update your `System.config` to what they have. As well as changing all imports of the form `angular2/...` to `@angular/...`. The router has moved to `router-deprecated`, and they are working on new docs of the new router